# Can't delete object from array

Tags: reactjs

I'm new with react and now i have a problem.I don't know how to delete an object from array. Every Article has a delete button. If i press the delete button and i console.log, it shows the correct object.

When i use splice, it deletes randomly and after 2 clicks, is emptying my entire array. What i need to use to delete the correct object, as the console.log show me?

Objects are inserted in another component and rendered.

Here is my code:

```
class Article extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);   
    this.state = {
       deleteArray: this.props.entireArray
    };
     this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this); 
}

   onClickDelete = () => {
   /* this.setState({
    deleteArray: this.props.articles.splice(this.props.key, 1)
  }); */ 
  console.log("delete", this.props.articles)
} 

   getArray = () => {
          this.props.sendData(this.state.deleteArray);
  } 


    onClickHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.onClickDelete();
       this.getArray();
    }

   render() {

      return (
        <div className="articleContainer">
          <div className="articleTitle"> <Link to={
            {
              pathname: "/" + this.props.articles.url + ':' + this.props.articles.id,
              state: {singleTitle: this.props.articles.title,
                      singleDate: this.props.articles.date,
                      singleText: this.props.articles.text
              }
            }
            }>{this.props.articles.title}</Link></div>
            <button onClick={this. onClickHandler} type="submit">Delete</button>
          <div className="articleDate"><FontAwesome name="clock-o"/> {this.props.articles.date}</div>
          <TextTruncate
            className="articleTruncate"
            line={1}
            truncateText="…"
            text={this.props.articles.text}

          />

        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because splice returns a new array which contains only the deleted item(s). Hence, when you set a new state, you are assigning only the deleted item as the new state of the deleteArray property.

if you want to retain the original array and delete just one item,

```
let articles = this.props.articles;
this.props.articles.splice(this.props.key, 1);
this.setState({
   deleteArray: articles
});
```